# Run a php update file from javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am trying to run a update to mysql when a link in a table is clicked.
For this I have made 3 files:

movies.php

```html
<html>
<head>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script src="video.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<?php

include 'combo_new.php';
include 'config.php';
include 'opendb.php';

$ndate = $_POST['ndate'];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT *
            FROM DayMovie 
            WHERE FileDate LIKE '$ndate%' ORDER BY FileDate DESC") 
or die(mysql_error());  
echo "<table border='0'>";
echo "<tr> <th>Dato</th><th>Visninger</th><th>Handling</th></tr>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
 echo "<tr><td>";
 echo date('d.m.Y', strtotime($row['FileDate']));
 echo "</td><td>";
 echo $row['Counter'];
 echo "</td><td>";
 echo "<a href='alldaymovies/{$row['FileName']}' onclick='playVideo(this.href, {$row['FileName']});' onkeypress='playVideo(this.href, {$row['FileName']});'>Se film</a>";
 echo "</td></tr>";        
} 
echo "</table>";

include 'closedb.php';
?>

</html>
```

video.js

```html
function playVideo(filename)
{
 $.post( "update.php" {"filename":filename},
 function( data ) {
 alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
});
}
```

update.php

```html
<?php

include 'config.php';
include 'opendb.php';

$filename = $_POST['filename'];

$result = mysql_query("UPDATE DayMovie SET Counter=Counter+1 WHERE FileName='$filename'") 
or die(mysql_error());

include 'closedb.php';
?>
```

However theres something not correct here... Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

Comment: what is your problem? which errors are you getting? what exactly is not working?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is probably that your user is already redirect to the other page before the call to update.php got finished. Keep in mind that if you redirect the browser to another page that request that are busy get cancelled.

To test if this is really the problem try to replace the href of the "a" element with "#".
And change your playVideo function to look like this:

```html
function playVideo(filename)
{
 $.post( "update.php" {"filename":filename},
 function( data ) {
 alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
    setTimeout(function(){ document.location.href="alldaymovies/" + filename;}, 300);
});
}
```